# Find irreducible representations of a reducible representation of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Consider the complete graph $K_4$ with $4$ vertices, and choose some orientation for the edges. 
The symmetric group $S_4$ acts on the vertices and thereby also induces an action on the (oriented) edges. Since there are $6$ edges, I can say that this gives me a representation $\rho$ of $S_4$ on $\mathbb{Q}^6$.

I don't know much about representation theory, so my question is this:

**How do I find the irreducible representations of $\rho$?**

**Ideas so far:** I'm pretty sure that there is no non-zero element of $\mathbb{Q}^6$ which is invariant under this $S_4$-action. This means that $\rho$ has no $1$-dimensional irreducible subrepresentation, correct?
Other than $1$-dimensionals, $S_4$ has one $2$-dimensional irreducible representation and two $3$-dimensionals.
Since $\rho$ is $6$-dimensional, it is therefore either a direct sum of three $2$-dimensional irreducible representations or a direct sum of two $3$-dimensional irreducible representations. But how do I find which it is?

**Update/Another idea:** The complete graph has the shape of a tetrahedron.
Name the vertices $v_1, \ldots, v_4$ and the edges $a_1, \ldots, a_6$ and fix some orientation of the edges. Let $W \cong \mathbb{Q}^6$ be the space generated by the edges (over $\mathbb{Q}$). Consider the $3$-dimensional space $U_1$ generated by three elements $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in W$, each of which is a sum of three different edges that lie on one of the sides of the tetrahedron. In my case, I've chosen
$$x_1 = a_1 +a_2+a_3, \hspace{2mm} x_2 = a_3+a_4-a_6, \hspace{2mm} x_3 = a_1+a_5-a_6$$
(but I'm guessing the choice shouldn't matter). 
Now the $S_4$-action sends sides of the tetrahedron to sides of the tetrahedron.
So this implies that the space $U_1$ is invariant under the $S_4$-action and therefore an irreducible representation.

Similarly, one can define a space $U_2$ generated by three elements $y_1, y_2,y_3 \in W$, each of which is again a sum of three different edges that are incident to one vertex, I'm going to call these the edges of a "cap" of the tetrahedron. 
In my case, I've chosen
$$y_1 = a_1-a_2-a_5, \hspace{2mm} y_2 = a_2 -a_3-a_6, \hspace{2mm} y_3=a_4+a_5+a_6$$
(again I guess the choice shouldn't matter).
The $S_4$-action again sends "caps" of the tetrahedron to other "caps", which implies that $U_2$ is invariant under the $S_4$-action and therefore an irreducible representation.

Since $x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2,y_3$  together form a basis of $W$, it follows that $W= U_1 \oplus U_2$ is a direct sum decomposition into irreducible representations.

By calculating the effect of the elements $id, (1,2), (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3) \in S_4$ (which represent all conjugacy classes of $S_4$) on $x_1, x_2, x_3$, one finds that the character of this representation $\chi_{U_1}$ corresponds to the character of the product of the standard and sign representation of $S_4$. Therefore the representation of $S_4$ on $U_1$ is the product of the standard and sign representation.
Similarly, one finds that the representation of $S_4$ on $U_2$ is the standard representation.

**Could someone comment on the above explanations? Do they make sense?**

**Edit:** The precise edges that I've used above are the following (where $(v_i, v_j)$ denotes the edge directed from vertex $v_i$ toward vertex $v_j$):
$$a_1 = (v_1, v_2), a_2 = (v_2,v_3), a_3 = (v_3, v_1), a_4 = (v_1, v_4), a_5 =(v_2, v_4), a_6=(v_3, v_4)$$
[image: Orientation Choices]

Comment: Wait a minute, a permutation of the vertices may reverse an edge. How do you deal with that?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I'm not sure I see your point. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: First of all, if you consider $K_4$ with oriented edges, then you do not get an action of $S_4$ on the edges since swapping two vertices reverses the orientation of the edge connecting them. Secondly, in general if a finite group $G$ acts on a finite set $M$ and you take the free $R$-module $RM$ with basis $M$, then $G$ always has a fixed point, namely the sum of all elements in $M$.

Comment: OK, let's put it this way: why are you orienting the edges?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I'm orienting the edges because the problem comes from this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024031/action-of-automorphism-group-of-a-graph-on-cellular-cohomology) I have about cellular cohomology.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Would you be able to explain why I do not get an action if I orient the edges? It's clear to me that swapping two vertices will reverse the orientation of an edge.

Comment: Suppose the edge $e = \{ 1, 2\}$ is oriented from $1$ to $2$. Then the permutation $(12)$ reverse the orientation. Are you saying that $(12)$ *fixes* $e$ (and then you are disregarding the orientations), or perhaps you are saying that $(12)$ sends $e$ to $-e$? In the second case, the answer to your question will depend on your choice of the orientations, I guess.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yes, I'm saying that it sends $e$ to $-e$. Okay, so it somehow depends on the choice of orientation, but what general statements can I make for an arbitrary fixed choice of orientation? Or in what way does it depend on the choice of orientation? For instance, I'm guessing that it can't be that for one choice of orientation I get a direct sum of $n$ irreducible representations and for another choice a direct sum of $m$ irreducibles, with $n \neq m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be the four-dimensional vector space spanned by the vertices. The six dimensional space spanned by the oriented edges, subject to the convention that flipping the orientation corresponds to multiplying by $-1$ can be viewed as the exterior power $\Lambda^2V$. The general theory of representations of the symmetric group with special emphasis of computing exterior and symmetric powers of representations is described very well in the warmly recommended book 'Representation Theory: A First Course' by Fulton and Harris.

Edited in: yes this makes a lot of sense. I started writing comments about this, but the system threatened to move everything to chat, so I write here. $U_2$ being standard is correct, see last two comments. $U_1$ being standard times sign is also correct. I wasn't sure first that it would actually be a representation at all. That is: I wasn't sure that any group element that maps a certain face to itself would always map the corresponding vector to either itself or its negative and not to one of the other six possibilities. However, after staring a bit at the nice picture you edited in I see that this is indeed the case: your $U_1$ is indeed a representation and then you can use characters as you did to see which one.

Comment: In this example, $\Lambda^2V$ decompsoes as the sum of the two $3$-dimensional modules for $S_4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay but which two? I'm guessing it should be twice the same (probably twice the standard representation). And is there a way to find a basis of $\Lambda^2V$ in which I the direct sum decomposition is easily visible?

Comment: Sorry, I thought "the sum of the two $3$-dimensional modules for $S_4$" was unambiguous, since there are precsiely two of them up to isomophism. You can use character theory to deduce this. I am not sure how to make it explicit- I need to think about that.

Comment: I was thinking about this too. I think I can see an explicit way to embed the non-standard 3 dimensional irrep into your representation, but not the other one, although there must be an explicit way for that too of course. So the thing is: the standard rep consists of points in $\mathbb{Q}^4$ whose coordinates sum to zero. The *other* three-dimensional irrep is the dual of this one. Hence it is easy to give four vectors in the dual to the standard rep that span this rep: the linear operators 'take the first coordinate', 'take the second coordinate', 'take the third coordinate' 'take the 4th'

Comment: continued... So inside the dual of the standard we have 4 vectors (let's say $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$) spanning the rep and they are subject to the relation $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 + \alpha_4 = 0$. Now if I'm not mistaken (but I didn't check carefully, you should check it) you can embed this rep into yours by identifying $\alpha_1$ with the sum of the four edges pointing out of vertex 1, idenitfying $\alpha_2$ with the sum of the four edges pointing out of vertex 2, etc. Certainly these four sum to zero as you have every edge twice, in opposite direction. Ctd below

Comment: You should check that the group action behaves as expected. So if this pans out we have one of the two 3D-subspaces. There must also be a nice description of the ortho-complement, I just don't see it yet.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for your answer and comments! Small typo though: there are only $3$ edges incident to each vertex, not $4$. But regardless I understand your argument of $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_4$ summing up to zero. Would you be able to have a look at my "Update/Another idea" in my question? I think we may be along a similar line (I actually wrote the update before I saw your comments:-))

Comment: @Vincent If you check my explanations in the question, I think I've found that the identification you gave for $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_4$ will correspond to the _standard_ irrep of $S_4$ and not the dual. But I'd be really glad if someone could comment on my explanations above.

Comment: Hmmm... I expect you are right about the standard rep, but I am a bit distrustful of the construction of the other rep in terms of faces. In order to make communication easier, can you please edit in the precise relation between your notation for vertices and your notation for edges? So a_1 runs from v_1 to v_2, a_2 runs from ... to ... etc?

Comment: In the mean time let me quickly say why I am distrustful: you say S_4 sends faces to faces, which is true, but every face here is represented by 8 different vectors ($\pm a_1 \pm a_2 \pm a_3$) which together seem to span a three dimensional subspace of the rep before even looking at any of the other faces.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks for your comments, I've edited my precise choices. I don't think you need $8$ separate vectors to represent a face. What I've done is to take a counterclockwise cycle around the face, which already uniquely determines the face.

Comment: Yes you don't NEED 8 vectors, it is just that there are 8 vectors available, the question is how many of these are mapped into each other under the group - to make your argument work it sounds like you need one vector representing each face and the group permuting these vectors without ever meeting any other vector representing the same faces in a different way. I was sceptical if that would work, but I will check now with the picture

Comment: Ok, yes, staring at the picture some more I see that you are right. The rep on the caps is indeed the standard, representation. You can see it by characters as you did, or by looking at the map from what I call $V$ above to the rep in question, sending each vertex to the corresponding cap. Geometrically it is clearly a homomorphism and since the kernel of this map is clearly the sum of all vertices, the rep $U_2$ is isomorphic to V modulo its subrep spanned by the sum of vertices which is the definition of the standard rep.

Comment: Since I also still believe in my argument above, the conclusion must be that the dual of the standard rep is isomorphic to the standard itself and not to standard tensor sign as I earlier (and apparently errornously) believed. I would like to see a more direct proof of this, but that is outside the scope of this question.